# PyCharm inspection error for module in a package

Tags: package, pycharm, inspection

Why does PyCharm's inspection complain about this?

```
import mypackage; 
mypackage.mymodule  # inspection hilights mymodule
```

The message I get is: " Cannot find reference 'mymodule' in 'mypackage' ".
However, the program runs without problem. Inserting `import mymodule` into `__init__.py` solves this, but creates other problems.